# ruby - can't write to logs in daemons

Tags: ruby, logging, daemon, daemons

Normally I can write logs with `Logger`:

```
//abc.rb
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new('foo.log')

$./abc.rb
```

But in a `Daemons` I got a permission error:

```
//xyz.rb
require 'logger'
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run_proc('xyz') do
  logger = Logger.new('foo.log')
end

$./xyz.rb
/home/raincole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:599:in `initialize': Permission denied - foo.log (Errno::EACCES)
from /home/raincole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:599:in `open'
from /home/raincole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:599:in `create_logfile'
from /home/raincole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:594:in `open_logfile'
from /home/raincole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:549:in `initialize'
from /home/raincole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:314:in `new'
from /home/raincole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/logger.rb:314:in `initialize'
```

I ran `abc.rb` and `xyz.rb` in the same directory and with the same identity. Why can't one log as the other can?

Comment: Does daemons set effective user id?

Answer (score 9):

Here's the reason. From [the Daemons documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/daemons/1.1.9/Daemons).

I have put in **bold** the relevant part for you:

> ### What does daemons internally do with my daemons?
>
> From a technical aspect of view, daemons does the following when creating a daemon:
>
> 1. Forks a child (and exits the parent process, if needed)
> 2. Becomes a session leader (which detaches the program from the controlling terminal).
> 3. Forks another child process and exits first child. This prevents the potential of acquiring a controlling terminal.
> 4. **Changes the current working directory to "/".**
> 5. Clears the file creation mask (sets umask to 0000).
> 6. Closes file descriptors (reopens STDOUT and STDERR to point to a logfile if possible).

So after you start the daemon you should either change your current working directory (`Dir.chdir`) to the directory you want to use for logging, or use absolute paths for your logfiles.

Comment: I don't recommend `chdir`. Daemons (and ideally all apps) should always use absolute paths. Accessing relative paths is usually a source of bugs.